# ¿Cómo mantener audio en segundo plano?

Tags: java, android

Hola tengo una *app* para hacer *streaming audio*, funciona muy bien cuando la *app* está en primer plano, pero no sé cómo puedo mantener el audio de la radio en segundo plano, cuando la *app* está en segundo plano se para de inmediato, aunque intenete con **doInBackground** mantenerla o eso creo en segundo plano y no va..... 
o si hay otros metodos de hacer una *app* de radio que funcione bien en *foreground* y *background* y me podeís pasar un tutorial o algo.

Si me puede alguien echar una mano se lo agradezco.

Mi código es este del **activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn;
    private boolean playPause;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private boolean initialStage = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audioStreamBtn);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!playPause) {
                    btn.setText("Pause Streaming");

                    if (initialStage) {
                        new Player().execute("http://streams.calmradio.com/api/29/128/stream/");
                    } else {
                        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                    }

                    playPause = true;

                } else {
                    btn.setText("Launch Streaming");

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                    }

                    playPause = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Boolean prepared = false;

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        initialStage = true;
                        playPause = false;
                        btn.setText("Launch Streaming");
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                prepared = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MyAudioStreamingApp", e.getMessage());
                prepared = false;
            }

            return prepared;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.cancel();
            }

            mediaPlayer.start();
            initialStage = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

El código del archivo `xml` que es muy simple:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/audioStreamBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/logo"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Launch Streaming"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: Lo que tienes que trabajar en este caso es los ciclos de vida de la aplicación. Por lo que veo el problema es que no controlas el caso **onStop()**
La actividad ha pasado completamente a segundo plano. solo controlas el **onPause()** La actividad va a dejar de responder a la interacción del usuario. Cuando yo quería realizar un caso similar también me toco repasar esto [limites en segundo plano](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background?hl=es-419) si tu aplicación incumple esas normas (que no creo que sea el caso) podría dar errores.

Answer (score 1):

Con un activity no se puede. Tienes que manejar la música como un servicio. Adentro de un servicio es donde controlas la música con la clase `MediaPlayer`. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public class ServicioMusica extends Service {
    MediaPlayer reproductor;
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private static final int ID_NOTIFICATION_CREAR=1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Creado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        reproductor=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio);
    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Arrancado"+startId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Context ctx=getApplication().getApplicationContext();
        PendingIntent intentoPendiente=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this,ActividadPrincipal.class), 0);
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(ctx).setContentTitle("Texto de titulo")
                 .setContentText("Texto de contenido")
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(intentoPendiente).build();
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;//encender led
        nm.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION_CREAR, notification);
        reproductor.setVolume(0.01f, 0.1f);
        reproductor.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        nm.cancel(ID_NOTIFICATION_CREAR);
        reproductor.stop();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

En la activity solo levantas el servicio donde controlas la música. Los servicios si funcionan en segundo plano:

```
public class ActividadPrincipal extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_principal);

        Button arrancar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_arrancar);
        arrancar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(ActividadPrincipal.this,ServicioMusica.class));
            }
        });
        Button detener=(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_detener);
        detener.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(ActividadPrincipal.this,ServicioMusica.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: lo he probado pero al ponerlo en segundo plano se para dentro de un minuto

Comment: En el androidManifest.xml necesitas agregar el servicio dentro del tag `application` así `<service android:name=".ServicioMusica" />`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el [método `setLooping(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setLooping(boolean)) para indicar si el `MediaPlayer` debe volver al inicio cuando termine o no.

Cuando se detiene al cabo de 1 minuto es porque debes poner el atributo a verdadero: `setLooping(true)`.

Comment: Esto no me parece que responda a la pregunta. Lo que se desea es mantener el audio reproduciéndose en segundo plano.

Answer (score 1):

también tienes que agregar en la declaración del service en el manifest el atributo

android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"

para que quede algo asi

```
 <service 
        android:name=".Control"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable"
        />
```

Comment: Pero como declararía el servicio?, eso es importante, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Esto se declara en el AndroidManifest.xml
Dentro de la etiqueta <application>

Comment: si agrego esto a mi AndroidManifest.xml no va a funcionar, se necesita algo mas no crees?

Comment: Tienes razón lo que me funciono a mi fue crear un IntentService en lugar de un Service
 Este te crea el metodo onHandleIntent ahi va lo que tienes en doInBackgraund y queda corriendo siempre en segundo plano

Answer (score 1):

Tu servicio quedaria asi

```
public class ServicioMusica extends IntentService {
    MediaPlayer reproductor;
    private NotificationManager nm;
    private static final int ID_NOTIFICATION_CREAR=1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Creado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        reproductor=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio);
    }
   @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio Arrancado"+startId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Context ctx=getApplication().getApplicationContext();
        PendingIntent intentoPendiente=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this,ActividadPrincipal.class), 0);
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(ctx).setContentTitle("Texto de titulo")
                 .setContentText("Texto de contenido")
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(intentoPendiente).build();
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults|=Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;//encender led
        nm.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION_CREAR, notification);
        reproductor.setVolume(0.01f, 0.1f);
        reproductor.start();
        
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        nm.cancel(ID_NOTIFICATION_CREAR);
        reproductor.stop();
    }
   
}
```

Comment: y lo arrancas como un servicio normal

Comment: Revisando tu codigo encontre que tienes configurado el onPause para liberar el media player
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
Este metodo debe ir sin codigo